# There is a problem in memory-management of object in lua programming

Tags: object, memory, memory-management, lua, coronasdk

I'm making a shooting game with solar 2d, everything was working fine but after some time I feel that the games frame rate is dropping, but I did steps to delete my laser when the task finishes

```
local function fireLaser()
    audio.play( fire sound )

    newLaser = display.newImageRect( mainGroup, objectSheet, 5, 14, 40 )
    physics.addBody( newLaser, "dynamic", { isSensor=true } )
    newLaser.isBullet = true
    newLaser.myName = "laser"

    newLaser.x = ship.x
    newLaser.y = ship.y
    newLaser:toBack()

    transition.to( newLaser, { y=400, time=500,
        onComplete = function()display.remove( newLaser ) end
   } )
end
```

I think what is happening, that `onComplete` calls the `display.remove( newLaser )` after 600ms but the function again called but in less than 600ms , say 400ms, so `display.remove( newLaser )`  dump the first object which is called on first clicked and remove the second one or say latest one, but if the player continuously clicking the fire laser button, and each click has a difference of less than 600 ms, then nothing would be removed. **Please Help me as soon as possible.**

Comment: Why is `newlaser` not a local variable returned by `fireLaser` to the caller? It seems like this issue comes down to using a global variable when it shouldn't be global.

Comment: @Nifim , ohh dude its working now thanks,  why I set it to global because maybe I was getting an error and trying random stuff in order to set rid of it, I don't know that much how Lua memory- management work, I'm new to it. can you explain why setting the variable local removing all the lasers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using `newLaser` inside of `fireLaser` you should define it as a `local` variable.

This will seem like a insignificant change, but when you do

```lua
        onComplete = function() display.remove(newLaser) end
```

you are creating a enclosed function.

> When a function is written enclosed in another function, it has full access to local variables from the enclosing function; this feature is called lexical scoping. Although that may sound obvious, it is not. Lexical scoping, plus first-class functions, is a powerful concept in a programming language, but few languages support that concept. - [*Programming in Lua: 6.1 – Closures*](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html)

This does not work when `newLaser` is `global` because each call to `fireLaser` is acting on the same `global` variable of `newLaser` rather than a unique `local` variable.